# Django Generic Foreign Key invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that uses a Generic foreign key

```
class Flag(TimeStampedModel):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

However when I try to save a new Flag where the ForeignKey is base64 encoded I get the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7_p1seHP7FR0KxN9+hHaCaNg'

It appears that the Generic Foreign Key can only be an int! How can I resolve this as not all my keys are ints.

How I get the error:

> u = User.objects.get(pk="7_p1seHP7FR0KxN9+hHaCaNg")
>   Flag.objects.create(content_object=u)

Comment: here it says it can be a char, right? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: "...For example, if you want to allow generic relations to models with either IntegerField or CharField primary key fields, you can use CharField for the “object_id” field on your model since integers can be coerced to strings by get_db_prep_value()..."

Comment: So it could be  ``object_id = models.CharField()``?

Comment: yes, I think so. Try it out. Read the docs, it can be anything that the original primary key can be cast/coerced to. you can also use a TextField, at a price in performance.

Comment: thanks that worked. could you post an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Just for the record: if your `User` class is the stock `django.contrib.auth` `User` model, then `User.objects.get(pk="7_p1seHP7FR0KxN9+hHaCaNg")` _will_ raise the very same error.  You didn't post your `User` model definition nor the full traceback so I thought it was worth a mention...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, yes, good point. I spotted that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) it says the Generic Foreign Key can be a char:

> ...For example, if you want to allow generic relations to models with
>   either IntegerField or CharField primary key fields, you can use
>   CharField for the “object_id” field on your model since integers can
>   be coerced to strings by get_db_prep_value()...

It can be anything that the original primary key can be cast/coerced to. You can also use a TextField, at a price in performance.